# Old widgets in web components not displaying from 1.0.3 and 1.1.0

Tags: wakanda

Wakanda older widgets within web components (on which mature applications are based) are not displaying properly.  This was initially observed with 1.0.3, and initially 1.1.0 (pre-release) corrected it.  But with the latest official 1.1.0 release, this issue has returned.  The behavior is browser independent.  Wakanda Server running on OS X.

I have had to freeze the version of Wakanda to 11.194922, which does not result in this behavior.

When I inquired about this previously, I got perspectives suggesting that the widgets are "deprecated."  Those that suggested this seem to be comfortable with the idea that years of developed mature apps on Wakanda can be "redeveloped."  This is not feasible in my case, and poses a show-stopper if this is a non addressable issue.

Can someone from the Wakanda team give me a clear input on this?

Thanks ...

Comment: Kirk, here is Ricardo Mello speaking to the topic as of a few months back: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqzMa1RpKQU (go to 2h 2min). According to this video, it sounds like no new features to WAF, but perhaps maintenance going forward.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the direction; but my inquiry is to understand if the widgets that are used in desktop applications that have been built over the past several years, are to be supported.  In this case, I believe it's basically an addressable bug.  I can install one version of Wakanda and the objects display properly, and then with no change to the underlying solution, a later version of Wakanda Server and they don't display.  These are basic text input and text widgets.  The alternative is to change a code and replace older widgets (NVA).

Comment: Just need clarity on support for desktop applications that are "back office" in nature.  Is Wakanda to be a mobile only platform?